# list<String[]>.groupby / orderby Linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

My code:

```
List<string[]> records=new List<string[]>();
.....
....
#Now i has list in records
var sortedRecords = records
                    .OrderBy(o => o[0])
                    .ThenBy(t=>t[3])
                    .ToList();
.....
```

I want to group by [0] element, sorted by [3] element in each group. I am not getting the right output. What's wrong?

Comment: So what are you expecting the output to be and what are you getting? There are just not enough details to go off of.

Comment: I edited its records that i declared at first

Comment: i want to records group by [0] element and sorted by [3] element in each group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GroupBy `o[0]` fist and then it will give you grouped result. Each group you can then order the items by `d[3]`, Since grouped ordered grouped list you can use `SelectMany` method to flattens it back to a list what you expected.

```
var sortedRecords = records
                    .GroupBy(o => o[0])
                    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(d => d[3]))
                    .SelectMany(g=>g)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: @Damith Can you explain it a little bit.?